# Double pointers vector in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

everyone. I was doing my home task and faced some confusing stuff with vectors in c++. I've got a vector of double pointers and I'm filling it in a loop. The problem is that each iteration the value of all members of vector changes somehow.

---

[image: Vector content on each iteration].

---

I don't understand why it's happening what I'm doing wrong and how It should be done the proper way. This things are happening in this part of code:

```
std::queue<TreeNode*> vertexQueue;
std::vector<TreeNode**> vertexVector;
TreeNode* tmp;
vertexQueue.push(Tree);

while (!vertexQueue.empty()) {
    tmp = vertexQueue.front();
    vertexQueue.pop();
    vertexVector.emplace_back(&tmp);

    //this loop is for the output
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexVector.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << (*vertexVector[i])->info.weigth << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (!isLeave(tmp)) {
        vertexQueue.push(tmp->leftBranch);
        vertexQueue.push(tmp->rigthBranch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: does the *location* of `tmp` (`&tmp`) ever change?

Comment: There's no need for double pointers here.

Comment: Actually, you're leaking memory. You assign a pointer to `tmp`, then add a pointer to `tmp` itself to the vector (all those pointers will point to one and the same pointer `tmp`!!!), then re-assign `tmp`. All pointers in the vector see the updated `tmp`, while the object previously pointed to by `tmp` is lost in nirvana (unless you have yet a backup somewhere)...

Comment: Will nodes *always* have two children or none? If they can have just one, then consider `if(left) { push(left); } if(right) { push(right); }` instead.

Comment: @Aconcagua how could this be leaking memory since there is no raw dynamic allocation?

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, nodes always have two branches, except for leaves.

Comment: @Quentin Got me: I naturally assumed that the tree nodes are allocated dynamically, but indeed, that's not explicitly given in the question... Maybe Gleb want's to clarify?

Comment: @Aconcagua The point is that I've already have finished tree and I don't need to create it. I want to understand why double pointer vector works in such way in my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer `tmp` is declared outside of `while` loop.

In `vertexVector.emplace_back(&tmp)` you add pointer containing address of `tmp` into vector which is always the same. In each iteration, you change only value of `tmp` what results in printing value under pointer previously assigned to `tmp`.

Comment: Yes, I understood this, but what is the proper way to do it? Making `tmp` double pointer and declaring in it inside `while` loop?

Comment: @GlebBessudnov Proper way is to have single pointers in the vector and copy `tmp` into each time newly. Be aware that a pointer is no different than an integer in this respect: `std::vector<int> v; int n = 10; v.push_back(n); n = 12; v.push_back(n);` – you have two independent *copies* of `n` inside the vector now, each with the value `n` had when being added to the vector. Pointers all alike.

Comment: Code you posted doesn't show any need to use vector of double pointers. As @Aconcagua said, single pointers in vector will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to understand why double pointer vector works in such way in my program.

Then draw on paper:

```
vector: [pointer]  [pointer]  [pointer]
            |          |          |
             --------  |  --------
                     | | |
                     V V V
                    [ tmp ]
                       |
                       |
                       V
                  <tree node>
```

Now what happens if you change the value of tmp?

```
vector: [pointer]  [pointer]  [pointer]
            |          |          |
             --------  |  --------
                     | | |
                     V V V
                    [ tmp ]
                       |
                        ------------
                                    |
                                    V
                 <tree node>  <another node>
```

Correct solution is not using double, but single pointers:

```
vector:           [pointer]
         (copies) /   |
            [ tmp ]   |
               |      |
               -----  |
                    | |
                    V V
              <tree node>
```

And one step later:

```
vector:           [pointer]        [pointer]
                      |   (copies) / |
                      |     [ tmp ]  |
                      |        |     |
                      |        ----  |
                      |            | |
                      V            V V
              <tree node>     <another node>
```